# how to redirect non logged users to login page and redirect to another page with saved data?

Tags: redirect, bookmark

m developing a page and using this free simple [Favorite Post plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/favorite-post/) to add favorites to users. currently its working for logged in users only. i need to show it to non logged users and when click on its button redirect to login or register page and after logged in redirect to same page or custom page.

this is for show favorite button code on front end : or short code :[favorite-post-btn]

this is for short for code display Favorited posts :[favorite-post]

if anyone can help me big it would me grateful..! thank you i will put the button code here :

function link_button( $post_id ) {

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    return;
}

$status = $this->get_post_status( $post_id, get_current_user_id() );
?>

<a class="wpf-favorite-link" href="#" data-id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
    <?php if ( $status ) { ?>
        <span class="wpf-favorite">&nbsp;</span> <?php _e( 'Remove from favorite', 'wfp' ); ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <span class="wpf-not-favorite">&nbsp;</span> <?php _e( 'Add to favorite', 'wfp' ); ?>
    <?php } ?>
</a>

<?php
```

}

Comment: Hi, questions about specific plugins need to be asked on the dedicated support forums - in this case for "Favorite Post", they are considered off topic here.

Comment: There's no action handler code here for clicking on the button, so I'd guess it's done in script. You'd have to enhance that script to handle the not logged in case.

Comment: thank you for the comment there is a action on the php file. can you help me to do this. im new to php language :)